# Определение цвета пикселя при клике

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, возможно ли узнать цвет пикселя на картинке при клике мыши (по которой был осуществлен клик) средствами javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно, с помощью canvas. Вот пример инвертирования цвета:

```
// Get the CanvasPixelArray from the given coordinates and dimensions.
var imgd = context.getImageData(x, y, width, height);
var pix = imgd.data;

// Loop over each pixel and invert the color.
for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
    pix[i  ] = 255 - pix[i  ]; // red
    pix[i+1] = 255 - pix[i+1]; // green
    pix[i+2] = 255 - pix[i+2]; // blue
    // i+3 is alpha (the fourth element)
}

// Draw the ImageData at the given (x,y) coordinates.
context.putImageData(imgd, x, y);
```

Comment: А, скажите, разве инверсия в JavaScript не поддерживается? (не подумайте, не упрек, просто интересно, как это происходит в JavaScript).

Операция инверсии в данном случае была бы логичнее с точки зрения самой процедуры, а еще вычитание - это по сути две операции, когда в данном случае достаточно одной. Единственное не знаю, правильно ли JavaScript понимает его для переменных без явного указания типа.

Comment: Код тут не при чем, как и его верность в плане алгоритма. Суть в том, что фукнция context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data вернет необходимый цвет пикселя, собственно ответ на вопрос :)

Answer (score -1):

При помощи стандартных средств JS нельзя. Хотя есть такой интересный плагин для JQuery под названием JСrop, который обрезает картинки на лету, возможно, его средствами можно при клике резать катринку на один пиксель и узнать его цвет. Посмотреть на пример использования и демо можно [тут](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=802).

Comment: При помощи JavaScript можно узнать цвет пикселя только если у Вас существует готовая карта изображения, где прописан цвет для каждого пикселя. 

2 Loki  - JСrop не "обрезает изображения на лету". Он только манипулирует стилями. Изображение остается как и было.