# Сгенерировать рандомную точку внутри треугольника

Tags: javascript, математика

У меня есть холст и три точки вершин треугольника:

```js
const size = {
  w: 1000,
  h: 1000
};

const peaks = [
  { x: size.w * 0.5, y: size.h * 0.2 },
  { x: size.w * 0.2, y: size.h * 0.8 },
  { x: size.w * 0.8, y: size.h * 0.8 }
];

function generateRandomPointInTriangle(peaks) {
  
}

console.log(generateRandomPointInTriangle(peaks));
```

Я бы хотел сделать функцию `generateRandomPointInTriangle`, которая может сгенерировать рандомную точку внутри треугольника

 `{x: number, y: number}`
Как мне это придумать - пока что без понятия

Comment: Привет! Есть у меня предложение, но не знаю, насколько эффективное. Ты можешь найти прямоугольник, в который будет "вписан" случайный треугольник (нужны **x** координаты самой левой и самой правой точки и **y** самой нижней и верхней). Далее генерируешь случайную точку в прямоугольнике и проверяешь, принадлежит ли она треугольнику. [Про алгоритмы можешь почитать здесь](http://cyber-code.ru/tochka_v_treugolnike/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сгенерировать два случайных числа `u,v` в диапазоне 0..1.

Проверить их сумму. Если она больше 1, сделать

```
if (u + v > 1)  {
    u = 1 - u
     v = 1 - v
}
```

Вычислить линейную комбинацию двух сторон треугольника (для вершин a,b,c)

```
x = ax + (bx - ax) * u + (cx - ax) * v 
y = ay + (by - ay) * u + (cy - ay) * v
```

Результат - равномерно распределенные внутри треугольника случайные точки.

Это эквивалентно генерации случайной точки в параллелограмме из двух треугольников

```
AE = AB*u + AC*v
E = A + AE
```

а если точка оказывается за диагональю, то она отражается в нужный треугольник (F->G) (можно её отбрасывать, но так экономим генерацию случайных чисел)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код Python для справки:

```
import random
def randomPointInTriangle(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy):
    u = random.random()   #uniform in 0..1 range
    v = random.random()   #coordinates in parallelogram
    if u + v > 1:   #in auxiliary triangle, perform reflection into target one
        u = 1 - u
        v = 1 - v
    #linear combination of side vectors
    return ax + (bx - ax) * u + (cx - ax) * v, ay + (by - ay) * u + (cy - ay) * v

print(randomPointInTriangle(0, 0, 5, 0, 2, 4))
```

---

Есть ещё способ, основанный на комбинации вершин

```
p = sqrt(random(0..1))
q = random(0..1)
x = ax * (1 - p) + bx * (1 - q) * p + cx * p * q
y = ay * (1 - p) + by * (1 - q) * p + cy * p * q
```

Если представить сечения треугольника отрезками, параллельными стороне bc, и на этих отрезках выбрать точку,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то координата q соответствует делению этих отрезков в отношении `q:(1-q)`, а координата p - отношению `p:(1-p)` отрезков, отсекаемых на сторонах AB или AC

```
|AP| = p * |AB|
|PQ| = q * |PE|
```

Таким образом можно сгенерировать точку внутри треугольника, однако при равномерном распределении `p` пространственное распределение точек будет неравномерно, они будут плотнее у вершины А. Поскольку площадь отсекаемого треугольника квадратично зависит от `p` (при `p=1/2` отсекается площадь 1/4), то для получения равномерного распределения по площади нужно воспользоваться методом Смирнова (Inverse transform sampling, inverse probability integral transform), и сделать распределение `p` согласно квадратному корню. Или, если на пальцах, то мы генерируем секущие линии сначала редко, потом чаще и чаще по мере продвижения от А.

Пример генерации 1000 точек вторым способом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я ещё не понял ничего, вечером попытаюсь подумать, думаю, это один из хороших ответов

Comment: можешь побольше графического пояснения добавить?

Comment: Я могу показать код на Delphi или на Python, хотя, в общем-то, всё описано

Comment: `u + v > 1` - это проверка что за диагональю получилось?

Comment: @Grundy Да, именно так. На самой диагонали сумма 1

Comment: Крутяк, заставило мозги поднапрячь, вспомнить векторы, геометрию. Только `способ, основанный на комбинации вершин` так и не удалось понять

Comment: @Sergey Philippenko Попробую второй способ описать.

Comment: У меня не получается, написал ответ с тем, что получилось

Answer (score 1):

Можно схитрожопить и решить графически.

Создается Canvas, в нем рисуется нужный треугольник (для других многоугольников тоже прокатит, кстати) и заливается цветом, отличным от фонового.

Затем пишется цикл, в котором отрабатывает функция, генерирующая рандомные координаты точки (в пределах Canvas) и берущая цвет пикселя с этими координатами. Выход из цикла - совпадение цвета пикселя с заданным цветом заливки треугольника.

[Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/8166/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5) написано про определение цвета пикселя на канвасе.

Comment: Можно создать массив из всех точек треугольника и выбирать рандомный элемент массива 

Comment: Не понимаю вашего ерничанья. Мой вариант рабочий, не требует математических расчетов и годится не только для треугольников, а вообще для всех фигур, в том числе нескольких, с пересечением сторон и наложением цветов.

Answer (score 0):

Находишь описанный прямоугольник, как писали в комменте (нужны x координаты самой левой и самой правой точки и y самой нижней и верхней). Далее генерируешь случайную точку в этом прямоугольнике, проверяешь, принадлежит ли эта точка треугольнику по алгоритму из статьи. Если не принадлежит, то опять по новой.
[Реализации алгоритмов, задача о принадлежности точки многоугольнику](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83)

`В основе алгоритма лежит идея подсчёта количества пересечений луча, исходящего из данной точки в направлении горизонтальной оси, со сторонами многоугольника. Если оно чётное, точка не принадлежит многоугольнику. В данном алгоритме луч направлен влево.`

Пролистай статью, найдешь код на JS

Comment: Такой подход я предполагал, но я хочу не костыльное решение, а что-то математическое