# Как поместить внутри трегольника рандомно точку на C++

Tags: c++, консоль

Хочу в отрисованом треугольнике поместить рандомную точку, чтобы потом точки ставились руководствуясь двумя правилами: выбираем одну из вершин треугольника и ставим точку. Следующая точка должна быть выбрана  по середине вершины и предыдущей точки. И наконец зациклить этот процесс до 25000 раз. Но вот не задача я не понимаю, как даже поместить первую точку в треугольник проект консольный вот код: (Он просто выводит треугольник и отрисовывает пустоту)

Отрисовку должна быть именно внутри треугольника.

Я не хочу от вас готовый код просто подскажите куда копать и, как поставить точку внутри треугольника?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    int n = 25;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n * 2; ++j)
        {
            if (j == ((n + 1) - (i - 1)) || j == ((n + 1) + (i - 1)))
                cout << '.';
            else
                if (i == n && j > 1)
                    cout << '.';
                else
                    cout << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сгенерировать рандомную точку внутри треугольника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1465104/%d0%a1%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Цикл который вы хотите делать 25000 раз теряет память о состоянии начиная от 53-й итерации назад. То есть исходная точка совсем не повлияет на результат. Можно взять любую точку в треугольнике, 53 раза повторить итерацию и получить ответ. Здесь 53 - разрядность мантиссы вещественного числа.

Comment: Разбейте исходный треугольник на четыре треугольничка построенные на вершинах и серединах сторон исходного. Тогда точка которую вы получите не может лежать в центральном треугольничке. В остальных трёх треугольничках распределение равномерное. Следовательно симуляция не нужна. Нужно случайно выбрать один из трёх треугольничков. В нём надо случайно выбрать точку. Как это сделать написано в "дупликате".